# Large DataFrame Join and update based on the condition

Tags: pyspark

I have two large dataframes(emp_df & mem_df). The information of the emp_df is not present in the mem_df except the one column which is the join column. Join is giving me the same number of records which are present in the mem_df table with extra column from the emp_df. But I wanted to have all the information into one dataframe/table so that while joining again, I'll be taking the respective data from this new table instead of again joining the two tables. Below are the sample data:

emp_df:

[enter image description here][1]

[Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtlxD.png) -> 7 Millions Family Number

[Member Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEN0e.png) -> 12 Millions Records

I did 'union all' to get all the records as shown below:
[Union all output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unfgp.png)

Now I want to update all the records of 'family_number' to its corresponding family_number, 'emp_contract' to its corresponding emp_contract, 'emp_cert' to its corresponding emp_cert as shown below:

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn5qD.png)

I did it through the for loop but unable to do it as its taking hell lot of time to update all the records. What would be the best possible solution for this scenarios. Need your help.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: what is the join column in this case ? I think its hard to read your question, going back on forth the pictures

Answer (score 0):

Let me k now if this helps:

```
emp_table=spark.createDataFrame([[100001,"Ashok",101,201],[100002,"Mahesh",102,301]],schema=["family_number","emp_name","emp_contract","emp_cert"])
mem_table=spark.createDataFrame([[100001,"Aseema","S"],[100001,"Adarsh","C"],[100001,"Akash","C"],\
                                 [100002,"Sandhya","S"],[100002,"Sam","C"],[100002,"Som","C"],
                                 [100002,"Sanskriti","C"]],schema=["family_number","mem_name","mem_dep_relationship"])
new_table=emp_table.join(mem_table,on=['family_number'],how="outer").drop("emp_name")
emp_table=emp_table.withColumn("mem_dep_relationship",lit("self"))
required_output=new_table.unionByName(emp_table.withColumnRenamed("emp_name","mem_name"),allowMissingColumns=True)
required_output=required_output.sort("family_number")
required_output.show()
+-------------+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
|family_number|emp_contract|emp_cert| mem_name|mem_dep_relationship|
+-------------+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
|       100001|         101|     201|   Aseema|                   S|
|       100001|         101|     201|    Ashok|                self|
|       100001|         101|     201|   Adarsh|                   C|
|       100001|         101|     201|    Akash|                   C|
|       100002|         102|     301|   Mahesh|                self|
|       100002|         102|     301|  Sandhya|                   S|
|       100002|         102|     301|      Sam|                   C|
|       100002|         102|     301|      Som|                   C|
|       100002|         102|     301|Sanskriti|                   C|
+-------------+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Outer join is good approach but not effective with Large dataframe as stated in the question. It will fail and cause issues on execution